Ordinal Event Ordering $P(E)\geq P(E')\iff Q(E)\geq Q(E')$, so we can conclude something like $P$ and $Q$ are the same measure?
Let $(S,\Sigma, P)$ be a usual probability space. $S=[0,1]$ and $P$ is the usual Lebesgue measure.
$E\in \Sigma$ is an event.
Given $P(E)\geq P(E')\iff Q(E)\geq Q(E')$,
Is it possible that $P$ and $Q$ are very different, for example the expectations $E_P[X]\geq E_P[Y]$ does not implies $ E_Q[X]\geq E_Q[Y]$ for some random variables $X,Y$?

We immediately get
$$P(E) = P(E') \iff Q(E) = Q(E')$$
Let $p=P(E)$, then $P(E)=P([0,p))$ so $Q(E)=Q([0,p))=f(p)$
Which tells us $Q$ is just some increasing function applied to $P$.
$P([0,x))=P([x,2x))$ so $Q([x,2x))=Q([0,x))=f(x)$ which gives us
$$f(2x)=Q([0,2x))=Q([0,x))+Q([x,2x))=2f(x)$$
By doing the same thing for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we get $f(nx)=nf(x)$.
From this it follows that for any $n \in \mathbb{Q}$ we get $f(nx)=nf(x)$, and because $f$ is increasing we get $f(nx)=nf(x)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{R}$, telling us that $f(x)=rx$, so $Q$ is just a scaling factor, $r$, applied to $P$.
Hence
$$\mathbb{E}_Q[X]=r\mathbb{E}_P[X]$$

I just have one question: how to go from $f(nx)=nf(x)$ (rational $n$) to any real $n$? Do we need to use the countable additivity of $Q$?

@dodo sandwich $n$ between two rationals, $q_1<n<q_2$ then because $f$ is increasing we have
$$f(q_1 x) \le f(nx) \le f(q_2 x)$$
So
$$q_1f(x) \le f(nx) \le q_2f(x)$$
and by making $q_1$ and $q_2$ as close to $n$ as we like, this means $f(nx)$ has to be exactly $nf(x)$.

There are many irrationals between $q_1$ and $q_2$ no matter how close they are. For example $n=q_1+\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(q_2-q_1)$ and $n'=q_1+\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}(q_2-q_1)$.

We might need some convergence arguments

@dodo for any alternative $n'f(x)$ that you think $f(nx)$ might be, there will be a rational $q$ between $n$ and $n'$ (wlog) $n<q<n'$ so that
$$f(nx) \le qf(x) < n'f(x)$$
because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Which means $f(nx) \ne n'f(x)$ for $n' \ne n$. Hence $f(nx)=nf(x)$.
